# pandas boxplot contains content of plot saved before

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, boxplot

I'm plotting some columns of a datafame into a boxplot. Sofar, no problem. As seen below I wrote some stuff and it works.  BUT:  the second plot contains the plot of the first plot, too. So as you can see I tried it with "= None" or "del value", but it does not work. Putting the plot function outside also don't solves the problem.

Whats wrong with my code?

Here is an executable example

```
 import pandas as pd 
 
 d1 = {'ff_opt_time': [10, 20, 11, 5, 15 , 13, 19, 25  ], 'ff_count_opt': [30, 40, 45, 29, 35,38,32,41]}
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
 d2 = {'ff_opt_time': [1, 2, 1, 5, 1 , 1, 4, 5  ], 'ff_count_opt': [3, 4, 4, 9, 5,3, 2,4]}
 df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
 
 def evaluate2(df1, df2):
    
     def plot(df, output ):
         boxplot = df.boxplot(rot=45,fontsize=5)
         fig = boxplot.get_figure()
         fig.savefig(output + ".pdf")
     
     df_ot = pd.DataFrame(columns=['opt_time1' , 'opt_time2'])
     df_ot['opt_time1'] = df1['ff_opt_time']
     df_ot['opt_time2'] = df2['ff_opt_time']
     plot(df_ot, "bp_opt_time")
 
     df_op = pd.DataFrame(columns=['count_opt1' , 'count_opt2'])
     df_op['count_opt1'] = df1['ff_count_opt']
     df_op['count_opt2'] = df2['ff_count_opt']
     plot(df_op, "bp_count_opt_perm")    
 
 evaluate2(df1, df2)
```

Here is another executable example. I even used other variable names.

```
import pandas as pd 

d1 = {'ff_opt_time': [10, 20, 11, 5, 15 , 13, 19, 25  ], 'ff_count_opt': [30, 40, 45, 29, 35,38,32,41]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
d2 = {'ff_opt_time': [1, 2, 1, 5, 1 , 1, 4, 5  ], 'ff_count_opt': [3, 4, 4, 9, 5,3, 2,4]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

def evaluate2(df1, df2):

    df_ot = pd.DataFrame(columns=['opt_time1' , 'opt_time2'])
    df_ot['opt_time1'] = df1['ff_opt_time']
    df_ot['opt_time2'] = df2['ff_opt_time']
    boxplot1 = df_ot.boxplot(rot=45,fontsize=5)
    fig1 = boxplot1.get_figure()
    fig1.savefig( "bp_opt_time.pdf")

    df_op = pd.DataFrame(columns=['count_opt1' , 'count_opt2'])
    df_op['count_opt1'] = df1['ff_count_opt']
    df_op['count_opt2'] = df2['ff_count_opt']
    boxplot2 = df_op.boxplot(rot=45,fontsize=5)
    fig2 = boxplot2.get_figure()
    fig2.savefig( "bp_count_opt_perm.pdf")

evaluate2(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see from your code that boxplots: `boxplot1` & `boxplot2` are in the same graph. What you need to do is instruct that there is going to be two plots.

This can be achieved either by

1. Create two sub plots using `pyplot` in `matplotlib`, this code does the trick `fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()` with `ax1` specifying boxplot to put in that axes and `fig2` specifying boxplot figure
2. Dissolve evaluate2 function and execute the boxplot separately in different cell in the jupyter notebook

#### Solution 1 : Two subplots using `pyplot`

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d1 = {'ff_opt_time': [10, 20, 11, 5, 15 , 13, 19, 25  ], 'ff_count_opt': [30, 40, 45, 29, 35,38,32,41]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
d2 = {'ff_opt_time': [1, 2, 1, 5, 1 , 1, 4, 5  ], 'ff_count_opt': [3, 4, 4, 9, 5,3, 2,4]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

def evaluate2(df1, df2):
    df_ot = pd.DataFrame(columns=['opt_time1' , 'opt_time2'])
    df_ot['opt_time1'] = df1['ff_opt_time']
    df_ot['opt_time2'] = df2['ff_opt_time']
    fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots() 
    boxplot1 = df_ot.boxplot(rot=45,fontsize=5)
    ax1=boxplot1
    fig1 = boxplot1.get_figure()
    fig1.savefig( "bp_opt_time.pdf")

    df_op = pd.DataFrame(columns=['count_opt1' , 'count_opt2'])
    df_op['count_opt1'] = df1['ff_count_opt']
    df_op['count_opt2'] = df2['ff_count_opt']
    fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
    boxplot2 = df_op.boxplot(rot=45,fontsize=5)
    fig2 = boxplot2.get_figure()
    ax2=boxplot2
    fig2.savefig( "bp_count_opt_perm.pdf")
    plt.show()
evaluate2(df1, df2)
```

#### Solution 2: Executing boxplot in different cell

[image]

#### Update based on comments : clearing plots

Two ways you can clear the plot,

- plot itself using `clf()`
  `matplotlib.pyplot.clf()` function to clear the current Figure’s state without closing it
- clear axes using `cla()`
  `matplotlib.pyplot.cla()` function clears the current Axes state without closing the Axes.

Simply call `plt.clf()` function after calling `fig.save`

Read [this documentation on how to clear a plot in Python using matplotlib](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-clear-a-plot-in-python/)

Comment: Hey thanks! This looks fine, but the Code is just an example. I have to do this with 20 plots. How can I use my plot function?

Comment: Is there no way to delete the plot after saving it as pdf?

Comment: @theother 
Depends 
(1) why are you saving the plot is to look at later?
(2) When you say 20 plots, is it with 20 dataframes and 20 column names?

Comment: I don't use a jupyter or some think elese. I just run a script to create the plots, which are saved as pdf or svg. There are two dataframes as arguments. And as I show with this two plots, there will be more plots. Like "worse_time" and "count_worse" and some other data...

Comment: when you mentioned 20 plots, are you referring to the 20 columns in a dataframe? If so, you can utilise this script and modify based on your use case by adding in your other 18 columns.

Comment: Well it's possilble todo it like you suggest, but why is it not possilble to reset the plot? My problem is solved but it doesn't make sense in golbal... I voted up 6 h ago. Marking as solved follows of no better answer comes the next day.

Comment: @"Archana David"  why is boxplot 1 und boxplot2 the same graph? bplt1 comes von df_ot and bplt2 comes from df_ot. This are different dataframes on which the boxplot function is called.

Comment: @theother kindly check the updated answer on ways to resetting or clearing plots. I do Hope there aren’t anymore hidden queries. If so do update your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Just grab the code from Archana David and put it in your plot function: the goal is to call "fig, ax = plt.subplots()" to create a new graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
d1 = {'ff_opt_time': [10, 20, 11, 5, 15, 13, 19, 25],
    'ff_count_opt': [30, 40, 45, 29, 35, 38, 32, 41]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
d2 = {'ff_opt_time': [1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4, 5],
    'ff_count_opt': [3, 4, 4, 9, 5, 3, 2, 4]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
def evaluate2(df1, df2):
    def plot(df, output):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    boxplot = df.boxplot(rot=45, fontsize=5)
    ax = boxplot
    fig = boxplot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig(output + ".pdf")

    df_ot = pd.DataFrame(columns=['opt_time1', 'opt_time2'])
    df_ot['opt_time1'] = df1['ff_opt_time']
    df_ot['opt_time2'] = df2['ff_opt_time']
    plot(df_ot, "bp_opt_time")

    df_op = pd.DataFrame(columns=['count_opt1' , 'count_opt2'])
    df_op['count_opt1'] = df1['ff_count_opt']
    df_op['count_opt2'] = df2['ff_count_opt']
    plot(df_op, "bp_count_opt_perm")    

evaluate2(df1, df2)
```